# Chart JS not reacting to change in computed property

Tags: vue.js, charts, vue-chartjs

I have computed property:

```
computed: {
    drilldownData() {
        if (this.toggle_drill === "up") {
            return this.waterfallDataSmall
        } else {
            return this.waterfallData
        }
    }
}
```

And the `toggle_drill` is model variable connected to button-toggle component:

`<v-btn-toggle v-model="toggle_drill">`

When I toggle it the `toggle_drill` will change value from up to down and back without a problem.

However you can see in the reproduced example here:
[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-playground-xbgcv?file=/src/layout.vue)

That the chart only updates once and thats it. It should be updating as the `toggle_drill` is updating which this computed property indicates. It seems to be crashing after initial update but i have no idea why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

chart.js changes the chart data object and the original `waterfallDataSmall` gets overwritten after first change.

A simple fix is passing a cloned object.

```
drilldownData() {
  if (this.toggle_drill === "up") {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.waterfallDataSmall));
  } else {
    return this.waterfallData;
  }
}
```